# Factory method implementaion

Tags: design-patterns

I have implemented Factory method as following:

```
 class A
{

}
class A1:A
{

}

class A2:A
{

}
static class Factory
{
    public static A GetInstance(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            return new A1();
        else if (i == 2)
            return new A2();
        else
            return null;

    }
}
```

I want to use the Factory in the following class method f1(). The method f1() will be called from its derived classes.I can go by the  following approaches:

Approach 1:

```
class MyClass
{
    private A obj = null;
    public void f1()
    {
        obj = Factory.GetInstance(1);
    }

}
```

Approach 2:

```
class MyClass2
{
    protected  A obj { get; set; }
    protected void f1()
    {
        obj = Factory.GetInstance(1);
    }

}
```

Which approach is better? Do I need to make the properties and methods protected?
What the pros and cons of the approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

Generally but not always you want to inherit methods and not data. The f1() function will construct the obj using the factory so there is no need to have a set method. f1() could remain protected and each derived class could call f1() to get their own instance of the object but if you needed to share this specific instance with others you would just create a getObj public method inside of MyClass that could return a const reference in c++ or final in java of this type or a copy in c++ or a clone in Java ( not sure if c# exactly the same), but still have your private instance of obj in MyClass.

Comment: Woah! wall of text. Could you maybe break it up a little bit?